# What is the fastest way to iterate over dictionary keys in Python?

Tags: python, performance

I used to iterate over the keys of a dictionary using the `.keys()` iterator:

```py
for _ in dictionary.keys():
```

However, I saw the following way being used:

```py
for _ in [*dictionary]:
```

And then, while researching this technique, I saw another way being suggested as standard:

```py
for _ in dictionary:
```

Which of these ways is the fastest?

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416600).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried the following methods (see below for measuring details):

```py
def simplest(d):
    for _ in d:
        pass
    
def extract(d):
    for _ in [*d]:
        pass
    
def keys(d):
    for _ in d.keys():
        pass
    
def items(d):
    for _ in d.items():
        pass
```

With the results in the image.
[image: time of different methods]
The direct access (using the `.__iter__()` method) is the fastest solution, and arguably the most readable too.

### Measuring

```py
import time
def measure(method, dict_size):
    dictionary = {f'{i}': i for i in range(dict_size)}
    ts = time.time()
    result = method(dictionary)
    te = time.time()
    return {'name': method.__name__, 'size': dict_size, 'time': (te - ts) / 1000}

import itertools
time_results = []
for _ in range(5):
    time_results.extend([measure(method, size) for method, size in itertools.product([simplest, extract, keys, items], np.logspace(1, 7, base=10, num=7).astype(int))])
```

Comment: Would be nice if you do the comparison for the list compressions ... nice summary !